# Airflow - What do I do when I have a variable amount of Work that needs to be handled by a DAG?

Tags: python, airflow, mwaa

I have a sensor task that listens to files being created in S3.

After a poke I may have 3 files, after another poke I might have another 5 files.

I want to create a DAG (or multiple dags) that listen to work request, and creates others tasks or DAGs to handle that amount of work.

I wish I could access the xcom or dag_run variable from the DAG definition (see pseudo-code as follows):

```py
def wait_for_s3_data(ti, **kwargs):
    s3_wrapper = S3Wrapper()
    work_load = s3_wrapper.work()
    # work_load: {"filename1.json": "s3/key/filename1.json", ....}
    ti.xcom_push(key="work_load", value=work_load)
    return len(work_load) > 0

def get_work(self, dag_run, ti, **_):
    s3_wrapper = S3Wrapper()
    work_load = ti.xcom_pull(key="work_load")
    dag_run.conf['work_load'] = work_load
    s3_wrapper.move_messages_from_waiting_to_processing(work_load)

with DAG(
    "ListenAndCallWorkers",
    description="This DAG waits for work request from s3",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    wait_for_s3_data: PythonSensor = PythonSensor(
        task_id="wait_for_s3_data",
        python_callable=wait_for_s3_data,
        timeout=60,
        poke_interval=30,
        retries=2,
        mode="reschedule",
    )

    get_data_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="GetData",
        python_callable=query.get_work,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    work_load  = "{{ dag_run.conf['work_load'] }}" # <--- I WISH I COULD DO THIS
    
    do_work_tasks  = [
        TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f"TriggerDoWork_{work}",
            trigger_dag_id="Work",  # Ensure this equals the dag_id of the DAG to trigger
            conf={"work":keypath},
        )
        for work, keypath in work_load.items():
    ]

    wait_for_s3_data >> get_data_task >> do_work_tasks
```

I know I cannot do that.

I also tried to defined my own custom MultiTriggerDAG object (as in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790697/1494511). But at that step I still don't have access to the amount of work that needs to be done.

### Another idea:

I am considering build a DAG with N doWork tasks, and I pass work to up to N via xcom

```py
def get_work(self, dag_run, ti, **_):
    s3_wrapper = S3Wrapper()
    work_load = ti.xcom_pull(key="work_load")
    i = 1
    for work, keypath in work_load.items()
        dag_run.conf[f'work_{i}'] = keypath
        i += 1
        if i > N:
            break
    s3_wrapper.move_messages_from_waiting_to_processing(work_load[:N])
```

This idea would get the job done, but it sounds very inefficient

Related questions:

This is the same question as I have, but no code is presented on how to solve it:

[Airflow: Proper way to run DAG for each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082546/airflow-proper-way-to-run-dag-for-each-file)

This answer looks like it would solve the problem, but it seems to be related to Airflow versions lower than 2.2.2
[How do we trigger multiple airflow dags using TriggerDagRunOperator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806944/how-do-we-trigger-multiple-airflow-dags-using-triggerdagrunoperator)

Comment: In Airflow 2.3.0, Dynamic Task Mapping may solve this issue. Unfortunately, MWAA does not support 2.3.0 yet. Dynamic Task Mapping: https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-2.3.0/#dynamic-task-mapping-aip-42

Comment: yeah, that sounds like what I need.
I will keep looking for 2.2.2 solutions. Thank you