# Airflow TriggerDagRunOperator does nothing

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

So I have 2 DAGs, One is simple to fetch some data from an API and start another more complex DAG for each item.

This is my code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


from airflow import DAG
from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
 
from nop_collector_fw_scripts.fetch_data_from_fw_module import \
    get_data_from_fwmodule
 
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 10, 18),
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5), }
 
dag = DAG(
    "poll_cisco_asa_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Set your desired schedule interval
)
 
 
def fetch_tenant_data_func(**kwargs):
    # …some logic to get the tenants…
    ti.xcom_push(key="tenant_data", value=tenant_data)
 
fetch_tenant_data_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="fetch_tenant_data",
    python_callable=fetch_tenant_data_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
 
def fetch_device_data_func(**kwargs):
    # …some logic to get the device data …
    ti.xcom_push(key="device_data", value=device_data)
 
fetch_device_data_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="fetch_device_data",
    python_callable=fetch_device_data_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
 
 
# Loop through the fetched data and trigger new DAG runs for each device
trigger_dag_tasks = []
 
def trigger_dag_task_func(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs["ti"]
    device_data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="fetch_device_data_task", key="device_data")
    if device_data:
        for device in device_data:
           trigger_dag_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                task_id=f'trigger_device_dag_task_{device["name"]}',
                trigger_dag_id="device _dag",
                dag=dag,
                conf={
                    "device": device  # Pass the entire dictionary as a parameter
                }
            )
            trigger_dag_task.execute(context=kwargs)
            trigger_dag_tasks.append(trigger_dag_task)
 
trigger_dag_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dag_task",
    python_callable=trigger_dag_task_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
 
fetch_tenant_data_task >> fetch_device_data_task >> trigger_dag_task
```

If I run the DAG it completes with no error. I can see the data in XCOM. But the other DAG is never triggered.
I don´t See any problems in logs either. All completes with success.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your airflow version newer than 2.3? Because the answer might be different depending on it. Also, maybe you'll find [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44806944) interesting? I know it helped me back then when I had to do something very, very similar to what you're attempting.

Comment: Hi, I am using the latest docker image of Airflow, 2.7. I looked into the linked question, but I don't quite get the concept. Maybe you can share a snippet of your code or make a suggestion what I should change?  The "main" DAG does not really have to wait for the outcome of the "Child" DAGs. Basically start a DAG per item and forget is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok so... I've been doing some testing and even though a bit hacky, your version should work. Can you verify **1)** That the name (or ID) of the DAG to trigger in the `TriggerDagRunOperator` is correct? (In your question there's a suspicious whitespace in `"device _dag"`) **2)** That the DAG you want to programmatically trigger is active (erm... _"on"_ ? ) in the Web UI **3)** That you have passed `do_xcom_push=True` as an argument to your `fetch_device_data_task` (I doubt is this, because it's defaulted to `True` but just in case)

Answer (score 0):

Without having the full code and the same environment as you have, it's a tad difficult to fully test, but I believe your code (though a bit hacky, because is sort of dynamically sticking a bunch of `TriggerDagRunOperator`(s) in the DAG, which is not something Airflow wants to do and could be problematic with their visibility and naming) should work. In the sense that when you run `trigger_dag_task.execute(...)` a new DagRun will be created and started. Well... sorta/kinda, because what happens is that a `DagRun` object is added to the database with a state `State.RUNNING` but let's not worry about that right now.

Make sure that:

1. The DAG name... erm... ID... erm... the value of the `trigger_dag_id`  argument in the `TriggerDagRunOperator` is correct and has no typos. Just in case, though you should be getting an error if there were.
2. The DAG that you want to programmatically trigger is Active in the UI (there's a slider: make sure it's on)

   [image]
3. That the task that is going to push to Xcom has the argument [`do_xcom_push=True`](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-xcom/#The_do_xcom_push_argument). It shouldn't be this, because I believe most operators have it active by default, but just in case.

With all that in mind, you can try something like this:

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator


# Producer:

def produce_data_fn(**context):
    my_data = [random.random() for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5))]
    print(f"Returning {len(my_data)} data points: {my_data}")
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push('my_data', my_data)


def trigger_consumers_fn(**context):
    produced_data = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(
        task_ids='produce_data_task', 
        key='my_data')
    if not produced_data:
        return
    for i, d in enumerate(produced_data):
        trigger_dag_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f'trigger_dag_task_{i}',
            trigger_dag_id='SO-77357880-3-consumer',
            dag=context['dag'],
            conf={
                "my_data": d
            }
        )
        trigger_dag_task.execute(context=context)


with DAG(dag_id='SO-77357880-3-producer', schedule=None,
         start_date=datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1)) as dag_producer:
    produce_data_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="produce_data_task",
        python_callable=produce_data_fn,
        provide_context=True,
        do_xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag_producer,
    )
    trigger_consumers_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="trigger_consumers_task",
        python_callable=trigger_consumers_fn,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag_producer,
    )

    produce_data_task >> trigger_consumers_task


# Consumer:

def consume_data_fn(**context):
    print(f"Processing data point {context['dag_run'].conf.get('my_data')}")


with DAG(dag_id='SO-77357880-3-consumer', schedule=None,
         start_date=datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1)) as dag_consumer:
    PythonOperator(
        task_id="consume_data_task",
        python_callable=consume_data_fn,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag_consumer,
    )
```

And, sure enough, there will be a DAG producing values and triggering one run of the consumer DAG per value:

[image]

[image]

Notice that even though you "added" one `TriggerDagRunOperator` per datapoint returned, those don't show up in the DAG. That's one of the consequences of "dynamically" adding operators in the middle of the execution. As I mentioned before, the only thing you need from the `TriggerDagRunOperator` is its ability to create a new `DagRun` object in the database with a `.RUNNING` state. You could very well substitute it by:

```py
from airflow.models import DagBag
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.utils.types import DagRunType
from airflow.utils import timezone as dt
# ... more imports...

def trigger_consumers_fn(**context):
    produced_data = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='produce_data_task', key='my_data')
    if not produced_data:
        return
    
    trigger_dag = DagBag(settings.DAGS_FOLDER).get_dag('SO-77357880-3-consumer')
    execute_date = dt.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
    for i, d in enumerate(produced_data):
        # This is pretty much the same than
        # what TriggerDagRunOperator.execute() does:
        trigger_dag.create_dagrun(
            run_id=f'trig__{i + 1}_{execute_date.isoformat()}',
            run_type=DagRunType.MANUAL,
            state=State.RUNNING,
            conf={'my_data': d},
            external_trigger=True,
        )
```

This could be interesting in the sense that

1. It doesn't dynamically add tasks to your DAG (Airflow doesn't like DAGs whose structure can sort of randomly change over time)
2. It gives you a bit more control over the task's `run_id` naming structure, which could be beneficial later on in the UI, or to identify logs, or something like that.
3. It might be less confusing for both Airflow and humans that expect an Operator to produce tasks in the DAG (which is not quite what you are doing with the `TriggerDagRunOperator`: you're just taking advantage of the fact that its `.execute()` method happens to do what you want)

---

Now: if you could alter the producer data function (`def fetch_device_data_task`  in your code) a little bit so it returns a list of dicts (some iterable that can be `expand`-ed and that contains dicts), you could use the <strike>brand new</strike> new-ish (it's been there since version 2.3) Airflow's ability to create [dynamic tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) and pass those dictionaries as the triggered DAG's config:

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

# Producer:
with DAG(dag_id='SO-77357880-1-producer', schedule=None,
         start_date=datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1)):
    @task(task_id='produce_data_task')
    def produce_data():
        my_data = [{'my_data': random.random()} for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5))]
        print(f"Returning {len(my_data)} data points: {my_data}")
        return my_data


    run_dags = TriggerDagRunOperator.partial(
        task_id='trigger_consumers_task',
        trigger_dag_id='SO-77357880-1-consumer',
    ).expand(
        conf=produce_data()
    )


# Consumer:
def consume_data_fn(**context):
    print(f"Processing data point {context['dag_run'].conf.get('my_data')}")


with DAG(dag_id='SO-77357880-1-consumer', schedule=None,
         start_date=datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1)) as dag_consumer:
    PythonOperator(
        task_id="consume_data",
        python_callable=consume_data_fn,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag_consumer,
    )
```

Or... who knows... Now that you've seen the ability that newer (>= version 2.3) Airflows have to create dynamic tasks, maybe you'll decide that you don't need a separate DAG, after all